# Creating store instance in Extjs 2.3.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store, extjs2

I have a combobox and I want to create a new store instance of that combo.
I can see a store instance can be created by `Ext.create('My.Store')`
but this is not availabel in `Extjs 2.3.0`

I tried

```
var comb= new this.combobox1.store; // Gives error store is not a constructor
```

and

```
var comb= new this.combobox1.getStore(); // com is undefined here
```

Any ides.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year late, but better late than never, since I came across it as unanswered, try this:

First create your store:

```
 var myComboStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     storeId:'myComboStore',
     fields: ['name', 'value'], 
     data: [
         {'name':'shelf1', 'value':'shelf1 val'}, 
         {'name':'shelf2', 'value':'shelf2 val'}, 
         {'name':'shelf3', 'value':'shelf3 val'}, 
         {'name':'shelf4', 'value':'shelf4 val'}  
     ] 
 });
```

Then in your combo config, assign the store. This panel (fp) is a simple form to hold the example combo.

```
var fp = {
  xtype      : 'form',
  frame      : true,
  labelWidth : 110,
    items: 
     {
         xtype: 'combobox',
         fieldLabel: 'My Combo',
         displayField: 'name',
         width: 320,
         store: myComboStore, // ASSIGN STORE TO COMBO
         queryMode: 'local',
         typeAhead: true,
         emptyText : '-none-',
         listeners : {
          //click events for item selection goes here
        }
    }

}
```

create a window for the panel to go in

```
  new Ext.Window({
      title   : '',
      layout  : 'fit',
      height  : 180,
      width   : 320,
      border   : false,
      items   : fp
  }).show();
```

Working Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cta